# How to create a quiz app without multiple choice?

Tags: database, web-development, machine-learning

So I'm trying to make a quiz app where the answers should be typed rather than multiple choice. However, even though there is always one right answer, in english, we have many ways of writing the same thing.

E.g. Q: What is the definition of obesity. A: When a person weighs over 20% more than the recommended weight for their height.

However, a user could write: when someone is more than 20% heavier than their recommended weight based on height.

So my question is, how do I account for all types of correct answers? Machine learning?

Comment: Theoretically, machine learning, yes. But practically, the number of incorrect judgements will be too high. For an entertainment app, this would just lead to frustrated users, for an app intended for real tests it will most likely be completely unacceptable.

Comment: thank you, i guess multiple choice is my only option

Answer (score 1):

"Machine learning" is essentially possible for any problem that can be digitally approached. It's the machine equivalent of "I learn how to do solve [problem]", which logically is always the solution to [problem].

Given the range of freedom in human speech, you're not going to have a good time with machine learning. Trying to account for any possible phrasing anyone will use, likely also accounting for typo's and minor inconsistencies that humans still understand, is going to requires a data source much vaster than the user base your app is going to be targeting anyway.

---

It's nigh impossible to account for the variation in human speech patterns,simply because humans are so very creative with words. Think of the difficulties in translating text. Machines have gotten quite good at it, but they still mess up.

A much better approach here is to limit the input freedom that your users get. Let's look at the example you gave. What part of the answer is the part that proves to you whether the user knows the answer or not? I'm guessing it is this:

> .... . ...... ...... over 20% .... .... ... recommended weight ... ..... ......

Keep in mind, this is just an example. Based on the context, you maybe don't care that the user knows the exact percentage and would score "over the recommended weight" as correct.

Since this is the only part you care about, you can hardcode the rest.

> **Q** What is the definition of obesity?
>   **A** When a person weighs over [textbox1] % more than the [textbox2] for their height.

This dramatically decreases your users' freedom, meaning you only have to account for a small range of possible correct values: [20/twenty] and [recommended weight/advised weight].

Note that this validation is an example. The person who creates the question should define the correct answer(s) and any validation criteria like allowing approximate numbers or not.

Comment: might as well do multiple choice then